# Getting a 403 response ONLY when posting to s3 from javascript? All other methods work fine

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm pretty confused on this one. I'm attempting to post some data straight to S3 from the client rather than bogging down my web server. I'm using `Python` with the `boto` library to generate the signature, and javascript to (hopefully) schlep everything over to S3.

This issue I'm running into is that javascript gives me the following error whenever I send the request:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

I've verified that (a) my keys are valid, and (b) that I *can* actually upload/download things from S3. I did this by uploading small test files via `Python`, as well as using plain ol' `curl`.

The basic setup I have is this:

1. js reads the form data on the website
2. makes a request to my web server to get an upload url
3. uses the url to make an ajax post request to S3

The server side is super simple. It just spits out a url to use for uploading:

```
c = boto.connect_s3(settings.S3_ACCESS_KEY, settings.S3_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
c.generate_url(5000, 'PUT', settings.S3_BUCKET, 'mycoolkey')
```

Which spits out something like this:

```
https://mytestbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mycoolkey?Signature=OX6vJCNjb4Pz3Fuzh0840qCnY5U%3D&Expires=1415394562&AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY
```

This output is the same that I used with `curl` to verify that I can actually `post` to S3

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file myfilename "https://mytestbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mycoolkey?Signature=OX6vJCNjb4Pz3Fuzh0840qCnY5U%3D&Expires=1415394562&AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY"
```

So, it's all well and good, until I try to do the same thing via Javascript.

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'https://mytestbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mycoolkey?Signature=OX6vJCNjb4Pz3Fuzh0840qCnY5U%3D&Expires=1415394562&AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY',
              type: 'PUT',
              data: 'sometestdata',
              success: function() {
                  console.log('Uploaded data successfully.');
              }
            });
```

I've set the CORS settings in S3 to allow everything from all domains (while testing), and as far as I can tell, the js should be making the same request as curl does.. so.. what gives?

Why would one request fail while the other succeeds when they're both using the exact same URL?